# Netsuite: Saved Search Function much like "Text To Columns" in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, search, netsuite

I am needing to export my NetSuite Class' in a saved search in the exact format NS needs for upload. This means I need the name and "subclass of" for the class. My best guess would be a "Text to Column" style function to achieve this.

Currently, I can call in the name (no hierarchy) field that gives me the class name ready for import. But for the subclass of, I need it to display the main class if there is one.

Example:

Column Output: Main Class:Sub Class
Expected Results: If sub class, Display "Main Class", If Not, blank

Thansk for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine a CASE statement for the "if/then" logic and extract the text with the SUBSTR() and INSTR() functions.  You'll need to add a Formula (Text) column to your search with the formula:

```
CASE WHEN INSTR({class},' : ')>0 THEN SUBSTR({class},1,INSTR({class},' : ')) ELSE '' END
```

This could also be achieved using regular expressions but to me at least, formulas are more transparent so they are my solution of choice for text manipulation in NetSuite.