# Oracle Netsuite Saved Search - Class Split like Text to Columns

Tags: netsuite

I realize this is another thread with a similar question:
[Netsuite: Saved Search Function much like "Text To Columns" in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698355/netsuite-saved-search-function-much-like-text-to-columns-in-excel)
but the answer only pulled the first Class, none of the sub classes.

What if you want all of the Classes split into columns?

"Class" could have many levels out to
Main:Sub1:Sub2:Sub3

Could have any number of sub classes.

I'm assuming I could create 6 (or more) different columns with each one resulting in each respective Main and Sub -

Column 1       Column 2         Column 3        etc.
Main            Sub1             Sub2           etc.

This seems like a common desire I can't find an answer to.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to extract the part of the string for the corresponding column.

### Method 1

***Main Class (First Column)***

`TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR({class}, '^[^:]+'))`

***Subclass 1 (Second Column)***

`TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR({class}, '^[^:]+:([^:]+)',1,1,'i',1))`

***Subclass 2 (Third Column)***

`TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR({class}, '^[^:]+:[^:]+:([^:]+)',1,1,'i',1))`

Extend this pattern using additional groups of `[^:]+:` immediately after the first '^' of the regex string to add extra columns.

### Method 2

***Main Class (First Column)***

`TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR({class}, '^([^:]*):*([^:]*):*([^:]*):*([^:]*):*([^:]*):*([^:]*)',1,1,'i',1))`

***Subclass 1 (Second Column)***

`TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR({class}, '^([^:]*):*([^:]*):*([^:]*):*([^:]*):*([^:]*):*([^:]*)',1,1,'i',2))`

***Subclass 2 (Third Column)***

`TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR({class}, '^([^:]*):*([^:]*):*([^:]*):*([^:]*):*([^:]*):*([^:]*)',1,1,'i',3))`

Extend this to additional columns by simply changing the value of the last parameter, up to the number of capture groups in the regex string - in the examples shown this will work up to 6 columns.  For more than 6 columns you would also have to add extra `([^:]*):*` groups to the regex string.

Comment: Method 1 works great!!!! Could you please explain the syntax of the [^:]+: ? What does ^ mean? I assume * is a wildcard? Is the 'i' a count? Many thanks!

Comment: In that context, the `^` is working as a *negation* operator.  So `[^:]` means "match any character that is **not** `:` (colon).  The plus sign `+` means "match one or more of the preceding element". Together, they match any string not containing the `:`.  Then we add a `:` so that it matches any string ending in `:`

Comment: `*` is similar to `+` but it allows a "zero length match".  IE: while `+` matches *one* or more, `*` matches *zero* or more.  This is required in the second method to allow the regex to match shorter strings.

Comment: The 'i' makes the match case insensitive.  It's not required except that we need to put *something* for that parameter, because we need to add the 6th parameter which specifies which of the *capture groups* (the groups in parentheses) is returned.